# Automatically compressing and renaming daily backup files in MSSQL with 7zip OR Windows scripting

Tags: zip, 7zip, auto, windows-scripting

MSSQL Backup Job can't compress daily backup files, I need to know how to script or if there any program that compress every backup folder in the same directory and with it's same name (for example 20230531230000 should return 20230531230000.zip or .rar) and delete the original file.

I hate windows.
Please advise and thank you.

I tried to do it using 7zip but maybe I didn't find the way.